# Wix - default installation folder - why not "Program Files"?

Tags: windows, wix, installation, windows-installer

I'm using Wix to create and installer for my .exe.

My directories structure:

```
<!--Directory structure-->
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="MyApp" >
      <Directory Id="MyAppBin" Name="Bin" />
        <Directory Id="MyAppRes" Name="Data">
          <Directory Id="MyAppResDE" Name="de" />
          <Directory Id="MyAppResEN" Name="en" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="MyShortcutsDir" Name="MyApp" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

I use `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced"  />`, so I get the installer with "Advanced" and "Install" options.

When I click "Advanced", the default installation path is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\
```

But when I choose just "Install", program is being installed under:

```
C:\Users\PolGraphic\AppData\Local\Apps\MyApp\
```

Maybe it's because default installation will "choose" "only for that user".

Anyway, **how to force installer to install under *"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\"* by default** (when I click just "Install" instaed of "Advanced")?

I don't mind if it will be for all users or just "that user" by default.

Comment: Try to set `INSTALLLOCATION` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on llirB's answer installs are by default on a 'per user' basis and that means you are getting ProgramFilesFolder set to that user's %APPDATA%.

If you want the install to always be in C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\ you need to set

> InstallScope="perMachine"

in your Package tag. This will define the correct windows installer properties indicating this install is for all users (aka. install into Program Files).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are creating Per-User installation and because of that the Windows OS will redirect `ProgramFilesFolder` to the user's Appdata, for more details please take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd765197(v=vs.85).aspx